# Express +Jest. Test files are running sequentially instead of in parallel

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I have an Express.JS server which uses jest and supertest as a testing framework.

It has been working excellently.
When I call my test npm script, it runs npx jest and all of my test files run in parallel.

However I ran my tests recently and they ran sequentially which takes a very long time, they have done this ever since.
I haven't changed any jest or npm configuration, nor have I changed my test files themselves.

Has anyone experienced this? Or is it possible that something in my configuration is incorrect?

jest.config

```
export default {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./__tests__/jest.setup.js'],
}
```

jest.setup.js

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '/conn'

// Override the dotenv to use different .env file
require('dotenv').config({
    path: '.env.test',
})

beforeAll(() => {
    connectToDatabase()
})

test('', () => {
    // just a dummy test case
})
```

EDIT: Immediately after posting the question, I re ran the tests and they ran in parallel, without me changing anything. If anyone has any knowledge around this i'd be interested to get a second opinion

Answer (score 1):

After intermittent switching between parallel and sequential for unknown reasons. I have found it work consistently by adding the --no-cache arg to the npx jest call.

See below where I found the answer
[Github -> jest not always running in parallel](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5818)